# Un-weighted painted vertices moving with bone

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I am trying to rig my model and need to weight paint the bones to the proper body parts. I chose to parent my model to the rig using empty groups, but after adding weight paint to, for example, the leg, this occurs: https://gyazo.com/7a71be9641c3366da4dde5027e725459 .

Could this be because I haven't finished weighting all of the bones? Why is this occurring and how do I fix it? I apologize if this has already been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking to see if any child bones (bones which move when you move the "parent" bone) of the bone you are moving have weight on the problem area.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that.